# How crop a part of image if it is white and more than 10 pixels wide

Tags: python, opencv

Here is the code:

```
low = np.array([140, 140, 140])
high = np.array([255, 255, 255])

mask = cv2.inRange(img1, low, high)
mask_off = cv2.threshold(mask, 10, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
mask_off = cv2.dilate(mask_off, None, iterations=0)

cv2.imshow('as', mask_off)
key = cv2.waitKey(0)
if key == 27:
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

output:

[image]

desired output:

[image]

Why my code is not cropping those lines

Original image:
[image]

Comment: Please also post the original image.

Comment: @Ahx I uploaded the original

Comment: iterations=0 makes the call to `dilate` useless. it does zero iterations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the `erode` function, which does the opposite of dilate [(see here)](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html).

The second argument to `erode` or `dilate` take the kernel, which in your case is a 10-by-10 array of ones. Also, you must do at least one iteration.

```
low = np.array([140, 140, 140])
high = np.array([255, 255, 255])

mask = cv2.inRange(img1, low, high)
mask_off = cv2.threshold(mask, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
mask_off = cv2.erode(mask_off, np.ones((10,10), np.uint8) , iterations=1)

cv2.imshow('as', mask_off)
key = cv2.waitKey(0)
if key == 27:
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: I would suggest erode+dilate to (mostly) restore the shape of the rectangle. this operation is called "morphological opening"

Comment: So are you telling this like I can erode a object in 10 iteration and the damage done on the object I want to keep can be restored by dilating for the same amount of time, That's very helpful @CarlosVazquez you should Christoph's  suggestion in your answer

Comment: yes, but *mostly* restored. you'll see its behavior when you search for "morphological opening". the quality of the result depends on the shapes in the subject image and the shape of the kernel/structuring element. for some cases it works perfectly (upright rectangles), for others it leaves visible artefacts. it will remove thin features such as the acute angles of the M letter in the first picture on this page: https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/open.htm